# C++ Issue with my code

Tags: c++, function

When I run this and after I select my number as a player, Computer returns me two outputs (instead of one...). I have no idea why, could you please help me explain why that happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int random(int a, int b)
{
    int num = a + rand() % (b + 1 - a);
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int myNum;
    cout << "Choose your number, human: ";
    cin >> myNum;

    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    int comp;

    string player;

    while(1) {
        comp = random(min, max);
        cout << "Computer: " << comp << endl; // why does this get called twice??
        getline(cin, player);

        if (player == "too high") {
            max = comp - 1;
            cout << "min: " << min << " max: " << max << endl;
        } else if (player == "too low") {
            min = comp + 1;
            cout << "min: " << min << " max: " << max << endl;
        } else if (player == "correct") {
            cout << "Computer found the number..." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and *edit your question* to show us the input that causes the output, and also *show* us the output (actual and expected). I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are mixing input using `>>` and `getline`. `getline` reads to the next newline, `>>` does not. After you have entered your number, there is still a newline left behind, you have typed it, but hasn't yet been read. The first time you call `getline` that left behind newline gets read, and the program doesn't pause. Only on the second time that you call `getline` does your program pause and wait for you to type something.

Simple way to fix the problem is

```
int myNum;
cout << "Choose your number, human: ";
cin >> myNum;
// flush pending newline
string dummy;
getline(cin, dummy);
```

Comment: Why not `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: @Norrius used like that `ignore` only skips one character, and there could be more pending characters (say a space was entered after the number). The more correct method would be `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` but that requires a lot more explanation.

Comment: @john yes, I meant the empty parentheses to indicate a function call... I had something like `cin.ignore(256, '\n')` in my mind.

Comment: @Norrius No doubt, ignore is the best solution since it doesn't require constructing an unused object.